# Opinions on protecting content: book/password/sub-domain?

Tags: users, domain-access

We are going to have a 'micro-site' specifically dealing with HR for possible candidates. There will be some data that will only be available with a login/password.

I'm trying to think which path is easiest, simplest to create and maintain.

We are using the Domain Access module and I've no idea if that will interfere with creating a separate sub-domain for this micro-site. I thought if I created all the content in a sub-domain (such as hr.example.com)and then password-protected all the content at that sub-domain (using Drupal 6 protected_node module) that would be simple to keep separate and not have any of the info somehow end up on the main domain.

Or, coding the 6-8 pages as normal in html/css/jquery. Then, creating a basic page node in Drupal and put all that code in that one page, password protect it so that we'd send a candidate the url of www.example.com/hr where they would have to login before seeing the content. The idea of sticking all the html in there is that the micro-site itself would only be in the one node, thus keeping all the content behind the password.

And/or finally, using a "Book" to keep all the content 'contained' and password protect that.

Not sure. We've had so many silly server issues (I'm not an IT person) that I want to be able to make it simple and not rely on LDAP/AD authentication...just Drupal's authentication.

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to see the problem but I can't. Do you need a page just available for some people? and if the people is logged in, they can access that page? in that case you can create a custom content type a set the permissions to access it just for logged roles.

Comment: I created an 'hr-microsite' content-type. Created an HR-Candidate Role but on the Permissions page, all I see are options for either Create/Delete/Edit hr-microsite/own hr-microsite content.. I just want to see "view hr-microsite content". Am I missing something? I would want a user Role to only see a specific content-type.